# How would ceramic coating inside the reactor affect heat transfer?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, materials, metallurgy, alloy

With the ceramic coating, would I be able to get its internal temperature raise upto 520.
I would like to get a reactor fabricated for plastic pyrolysis. The temperature would maintained around 520C. The material processed would be Waste Polypropylene and Polyethylene.

Pressure would be slightly less than atmospheric pressure outside the vessel.

The conditions inside the vessel will be mildly acidic.

There are quite a number of alloys which seems good. (SS316, SS314)

How would ceramic coating inside the shell affect heat transfer?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a "cold shell" design. Plain old carbon steel shell ( eg. A 516 ) with a refractory lining. The shell won't be hot , maybe 200 C. You may need both erosion resistant refractory and insulating refractory.

Comment: Fluor , KBR, etc would likely be happy to design something for you.